# Background continuous access to a users live location

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

I want my TG bot to have continuous access to a user’s live location. Is this possible?

I understand that TG can be given continuous access - but it seems to me that this privilege is not relayed to bots running on TG. Is this correct?

For the record, I don’t have a problem with an additional pop up requesting for such a permission.

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendlocation) :

> sendLocation:
>   Use this method to send point on the map. On success, the sent Message is returned.

So the user can share it's location via bot.
But you are looking for **"Live Location"** right? so you can do it :-)

> Period in seconds for which the location will be updated (see Live Locations, should be between 60 and 86400.
>   **86,400 Seconds / 60 Seconds = 1,440 Minutes**.
>   **1,440 Minutes / 560 Seconds = 24 Hours**

So you can have live location of your user but there is only **"24Hrs"** limit.

Thanks in advance